# Spring WebSocket Stomp Exception Handling

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket, stomp

I am trying to use Websockets and STOMP 1.2. I want to authenticate user using JWT on CONNECT frame and to return error message if authorization is  not valid. Here is channel interceptor

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    // ... Removed for readability

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel)
            {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                        MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

                if (accessor != null && StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand()))
                {
                    String token = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(authorizationHeader);
                    if (token != null)
                    {
                        Authentication authentication = tokenUtil.getAuthentication(resolveToken(token));
                        accessor.setUser(authentication);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new UnauthorizedException();
                    }
                }
                return message;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This way the error stack will have

```
    Failed to send client message to application via MessageChannel in session a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is com.example.error.exception.UnauthorizedException: You are not authorized. Please log in.
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:146) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:122) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:284) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:324) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:113) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:84) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:81) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:395) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageText(WsFrameServer.java:119) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:495) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:294) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: com.example.error.exception.UnauthorizedException: You are not authorized. Please log in.
    at com.exampleconfig.WebSocketConfig$1.preSend(WebSocketConfig.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:132) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

And similar error will be sent to client end connection will be closed.
But after the connection is closed, other stack trace is written as output:

```
2018-11-11 01:06:48.077 DEBUG 7259 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : StandardWebSocketSession[id=a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f, uri=/api/ws] closed with CloseStatus[code=1000, reason=null]
2018-11-11 01:06:48.077 DEBUG 7259 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Clearing session a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f
2018-11-11 01:06:48.084 DEBUG 7259 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Detected unsent DISCONNECT message. Processing anyway.
2018-11-11 01:06:48.085 DEBUG 7259 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.SimpLogging      : Processing DISCONNECT session=a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f
2018-11-11 01:06:48.086 DEBUG 7259 --- [tboundChannel-1] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : No session for GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=DISCONNECT_ACK, simpDisconnectMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=DISCONNECT, stompCommand=DISCONNECT, simpSessionAttributes={org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpAttributes.COMPLETED=true}, simpSessionId=a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f}], simpSessionId=a63cf95f-4a5b-ef34-b74b-3264ec6dd61f}]
2018-11-11 01:06:48.087  WARN 7259 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator : Unhandled exception after connection closed for ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=SubProtocolWebSocketHandler[StompSubProtocolHandler[v10.stomp, v11.stomp, v12.stomp]]]]

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:146) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:122) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.afterSessionEnded(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:611) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.clearSession(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:516) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:385) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:78) ~[spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:144) [spring-websocket-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:535) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:513) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:347) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:289) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor.preSend(ChannelSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-messaging-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:132) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I have no idea where `AccessDeniedException` came from and how can I handle this.

If I do not throw `UnauthorizedException` in `preSend` method, client will be connected and when it tries to send something, it will receive `AccessDeniedException`, because all endpoints needs authenticated user, and then connection will be closed and stack trace for `AccessDeniedException` printed few times.

What am I doing incorrect here and what is the correct way to handle this kind of use case?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi @Shawn-Ross, yes I found solution that was alright for me. I will write it as answer.

Comment: This is not the recommended approach to authenticate. So Websocket first try to establish connection over http protocol and it request connection upgrade request. Essentially thay passes through spring security. So If spring security authentication filters allow then your server will respond back on upgrade request and a socket tunnel will be created. That Authenticated Principal will be set in each Subsequent STOMP message received on same session/socket connection by SPRING. So all you need is to properly configure spring security filters to intercept websocket handshake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As solution for AccessDenied exception is that I didn't configured to allow DISCONNECT messages to pass through security. This is my configuration now:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages)
    {
        messages
                .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.CONNECT,
                        SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT, SimpMessageType.OTHER).permitAll()
                .anyMessage().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Also, I overrode `StompSubProtocolErrorHandler` so I could send custom message to my client about error.

Here is example:

```
@Override
public Message<byte[]> handleClientMessageProcessingError(Message<byte[]>clientMessage, Throwable ex)
{
    Throwable exception = ex;
    if (exception instanceof MessageDeliveryException)
    {
        exception = exception.getCause();
    }

    if (exception instanceof UnauthorizedException)
    {
        return handleUnauthorizedException(clientMessage, exception);
    }

    if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException)
    {
        return handleAccessDeniedException(clientMessage, exception);
    }

    return super.handleClientMessageProcessingError(clientMessage, ex);
}

...

private Message<byte[]> handleUnauthorizedException(Message<byte[]> clientMessage, Throwable ex)
{
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(ErrorCodeConstants.UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());

    return prepareErrorMessage(clientMessage, apiError, ErrorCodeConstants.UNAUTHORIZED_STRING);

}

private Message<byte[]> prepareErrorMessage(Message<byte[]> clientMessage, ApiError apiError, String errorCode)
{
    String message = transformApiErrorToJSONString(apiError);

    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR);

    setReceiptIdForClient(clientMessage, accessor);
    accessor.setMessage(errorCode);
    accessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

    return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message != null ? message.getBytes() : EMPTY_PAYLOAD, accessor.getMessageHeaders());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! ) Note that we should register our custom error handler in `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer#registerStompEndpoints`: `registry.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());`